# T-SQL - Minutes per hour between two datetimes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have to following data:

```
 | tid | startdate        | enddate                |
 | 1   | 2016-12-26 12:30 | 2016-12-26 15:30       |
 | 2   | 2016-12-26 13:15 | 2016-12-26 15:15       |
```

I would like to create a result with the hour number and then the amount of minutes the date time falls within that hour.

Example result:

```
 | tid | hour | minutes_in |
 | 1   | 12   | 30         |
 | 1   | 13   | 60         |
 | 1   | 14   | 60         |
 | 1   | 15   | 30         |
 | 2   | 13   | 45         |
 | 2   | 14   | 60         |
 | 2   | 15   | 15         |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how are minutes segregated

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need this result? Is there some greater goal here to which this is just one step? Feels like there is some potential for this to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Every tid is an user login / logout time. I need the logged in minutes per hour. So if three users are logged in for 30 minutes between 12:00 and 13:00 that would result in 90 minutes login time in the hour 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First You need a numbers table to get your hours from 0 - 23, which can be fairly easily created on the fly with a table value constructor:

```
SELECT N
FROM (VALUES 
        (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
        (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)
    ) n (N);
```

Then you can join this to your original data to split rows out into the number required. Then you just need a case expression to apply the correct logic for calculating the minutes:

```
WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES 
            (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
            (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)
        ) n (N)
), SampleData (tid, StartDate, EndDate) AS
(   SELECT  tid, CONVERT(DATETIME2, StartDate), CONVERT(DATETIME2, EndDate)
    FROM (VALUES 
            (1, '2016-12-26 12:30', '2016-12-26 15:30'),
            (2, '2016-12-26 13:15', '2016-12-26 15:15')
        ) d (tid, StartDate, EndDate)
)
SELECT  d.tid,
        [Hour] = n.Number,
        Minutes_in = CASE  
                        -- SPECIAL CASE: START HOUR = END HOUR
                        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) = DATEPART(HOUR, d.EndDate) 
                            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)

                        -- FULL HOURS IN BETWEEN START AND END
                        WHEN n.Number > DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) 
                            AND n.Number < DATEPART(HOUR, d.EndDate) THEN 60

                        -- START HOUR
                        WHEN n.Number = DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) 
                            THEN 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, d.StartDate)

                        -- END HOUR
                        WHEN n.Number = DATEPART(HOUR, d.EndDate) 
                            THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, d.EndDate)
                    END
FROM    SampleData d
        INNER JOIN Numbers n 
            ON n.Number >= DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate)
            AND n.Number <= DATEPART(HOUR, d.EndDate);
```

**ADDENDUM**

If you need to span days, then you could alter the logic slightly, generate a larger set of numbers to cover more hours difference, then rather than joining on the hour of the day, join the numbers on the hours difference from the start datetime to the end datetime:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    SampleData d
        INNER JOIN Numbers n 
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)
```

This means where the range crosses over days, then there is no issue, the hours just keep incrementing. e.g.

```
WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) - 1
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N1(N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N2 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N3 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N4 (N)
), SampleData (tid, StartDate, EndDate) AS
(   SELECT  tid, CONVERT(DATETIME2, StartDate), CONVERT(DATETIME2, EndDate)
    FROM (VALUES 
            (1, '2016-12-26 12:30', '2016-12-26 15:30'),
            (2, '2016-12-26 13:15', '2016-12-26 15:15'),
            (3, '2016-12-26 13:15', '2016-12-27 15:15')
        ) d (tid, StartDate, EndDate)
)
SELECT  d.tid,
        [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, d.StartDate),
        [Hour] = CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) + n.Number, 0)),
        Minutes_in = CASE  
                        -- SPECIAL CASE: START HOUR = END HOUR
                        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) = DATEPART(HOUR, d.EndDate)
                            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d.StartDate, d.EndDate) = 0
                            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)

                        -- START HOUR
                        WHEN n.Number = 0
                            THEN 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, d.StartDate)

                        -- END HOUR
                        WHEN n.Number = DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.StartDate, d.EndDate) 
                            THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, d.EndDate)

                        -- FULL HOURS IN BETWEEN START AND END
                        ELSE 60

                    END
FROM    SampleData d
        INNER JOIN Numbers n 
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)
ORDER BY d.tid, n.Number;
```

Comment: Nicely done, I was going for a similar thing with the hours and 60 - x, but hadn't gotten there quite as quickly. Have an upvote. :)

Comment: this is exactly what i asked for - ty. Although now i see the result i realize i need the date as well. As a startdate and enddate are not always on the same day - could span multiple days. I will try to do it with your input.

Comment: @phicon I have added an extra bit about how to solve this when the range crosses one or more days.

Answer (score 0):

**Method -I**

You can achieve this with a UDF (Another Simplest Way)

Lets build schema of your provided data

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB ( TID INT, STARTDATE DATETIME, ENDDATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1,'2016-12-26 12:30','2016-12-26 15:30'
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,'2016-12-26 13:15','2016-12-26 15:15'
```

Create one UDF to generate values between from and To

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_GENERATE] (@FROM_NBR INT, @TO_NBR INT)
RETURNS
 @RESULT TABLE(HR INT)
AS
BEGIN
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT   @FROM_NBR AS FROM_NBR,@TO_NBR AS TO_NBR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  FROM_NBR+1 ,TO_NBR    FROM CTE WHERE FROM_NBR<TO_NBR


)
INSERT INTO @RESULT
SELECT FROM_NBR FROM CTE

   RETURN
END
```

Now query for data by calling the function.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  TID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,DATEPART(HH,STARTDATE) FROM_HR , DATEPART(HH,ENDDATE) TO_HR FROM #TAB T
)
SELECT C1.TID,F.HR,  COALESCE(DATEPART(MINUTE,FRM_HR_MINUTS.STARTDATE),DATEPART(MINUTE,TO_HR_MINUTS.ENDDATE),60 ) 
FROM CTE C1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM DBO.[FN_GENERATE] (C1.FROM_HR, C1.TO_HR)
)AS F
LEFT JOIN CTE FRM_HR_MINUTS ON C1.TID= FRM_HR_MINUTS.TID AND DATEPART(HH,FRM_HR_MINUTS.STARTDATE)= F.HR 
LEFT JOIN CTE TO_HR_MINUTS ON C1.TID= TO_HR_MINUTS.TID AND DATEPART(HH,TO_HR_MINUTS.ENDDATE)= F.HR
```

> Edit :

**Method - II**

Without using UDF & using `MASTER.DBO.SPT_VALUES`

```
;WITH CTE AS (

--PREPARING START HR, END HR, START_MIN, END_MIN  FROM #TAB
SELECT  TID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE
,DATEPART(HH,STARTDATE) FROM_HR 
, DATEPART(HH,ENDDATE) TO_HR
, DATEPART(MINUTE, STARTDATE) AS STARTMIN
, DATEPART(MINUTE, ENDDATE) ENDMIN 

FROM #TAB T
)

SELECT TID
, NUMBER AS HRS
--if Outer APply produce Null Display Minutes from CTE else 60 Mins
, CASE ISNULL(OA.FRM_MINS, C1.STARTMIN) + ISNULL(TO_MINS,C1.ENDMIN)  
        WHEN 0
            THEN 60
        ELSE ISNULL(OA.FRM_MINS,  C1.STARTMIN) + ISNULL(TO_MINS,C1.ENDMIN)
        END AS MINS
FROM CTE C1
OUTER APPLY  --JOINING NUMBERS BETWEEN FROM_HR & TO_HR using MASTER.DBO.SPT_VALUES 
(
    SELECT NUMBER
    --IF FROM_HR matched NULL Else 0
    , CASE C1.FROM_HR WHEN NUMBER THEN NULL ELSE 0 END AS FRM_MINS  

    --IF TO_HR matched NULL Else 0 
    ,CASE C1.TO_HR WHEN NUMBER THEN NULL ELSE 0 END AS TO_MINS       

    FROM MASTER.DBO.SPT_VALUES 
    WHERE [type]='P' AND number>0 AND number BETWEEN FROM_HR AND TO_HR

)AS OA
```