# T-SQL - Seconds per hour between two datetimes across 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have the following data for user login and logoff times:

```
 | UserID | StartDate         |EndDate              |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 00:11:51 | 06/24/2018 01:03:38 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 02:12:38 | 06/24/2018 02:15:51 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 02:28:08 | 06/24/2018 02:36:31 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 03:07:13 | 06/24/2018 06:02:05 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 07:33:39 | 06/24/2018 07:33:40 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 08:19:19 | 06/24/2018 12:20:03 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 12:26:55 | 06/24/2018 13:30:17 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 14:07:42 | 06/24/2018 14:53:03 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 15:15:20 | 06/24/2018 15:33:01 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 16:42:00 | 06/24/2018 16:58:13 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 17:35:04 | 06/24/2018 17:49:01 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 18:49:26 | 06/24/2018 19:26:18 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 20:06:46 | 06/24/2018 21:00:07 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 22:35:51 | 06/24/2018 22:43:57 |
 | 1033 | 06/24/2018 23:00:52 | 06/25/2018 01:24:53 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 02:01:58 | 06/25/2018 02:03:47 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 03:01:57 | 06/25/2018 03:45:59 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 04:24:16 | 06/25/2018 04:43:52 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 05:16:15 | 06/25/2018 07:39:28 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 08:49:23 | 06/25/2018 09:12:06 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 13:38:20 | 06/25/2018 15:16:25 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 15:16:28 | 06/25/2018 16:54:34 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 17:35:24 | 06/25/2018 18:25:38 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 18:58:41 | 06/25/2018 19:20:56 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 19:46:27 | 06/25/2018 19:47:33 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 20:14:08 | 06/25/2018 20:40:20 |
 | 1033 | 06/25/2018 21:11:01 | 06/26/2018 00:36:56 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 00:50:43 | 06/26/2018 09:43:53 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 10:32:58 | 06/26/2018 10:33:38 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 11:01:29 | 06/26/2018 11:41:24 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 13:56:29 | 06/26/2018 14:52:08 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 15:40:07 | 06/26/2018 16:38:18 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 16:56:33 | 06/26/2018 17:19:14 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 18:37:33 | 06/26/2018 19:10:44 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 19:34:44 | 06/26/2018 21:30:06 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 21:43:55 | 06/26/2018 21:47:51 |
 | 1033 | 06/26/2018 23:03:17 | 06/27/2018 04:26:50 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 07:41:10 | 06/27/2018 07:41:11 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 07:41:23 | 06/27/2018 09:56:05 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 11:31:27 | 06/27/2018 12:05:42 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 12:48:28 | 06/27/2018 12:49:12 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 13:43:48 | 06/27/2018 14:13:04 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 15:13:32 | 06/27/2018 15:46:44 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 17:09:44 | 06/27/2018 17:16:15 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 18:01:28 | 06/27/2018 18:35:04 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 19:21:18 | 06/27/2018 19:33:47 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 20:01:51 | 06/27/2018 20:04:29 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 20:45:42 | 06/27/2018 22:13:48 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 23:14:33 | 06/27/2018 23:28:31 |
 | 1033 | 06/27/2018 23:57:57 | 06/28/2018 04:16:47 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 04:48:50 | 06/28/2018 04:50:12 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 06:00:36 | 06/28/2018 08:14:20 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 08:53:19 | 06/28/2018 09:09:52 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 09:28:04 | 06/28/2018 10:07:02 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 10:30:47 | 06/28/2018 11:07:06 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 12:23:48 | 06/28/2018 12:26:52 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 13:12:23 | 06/28/2018 13:24:10 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 13:50:18 | 06/28/2018 13:59:04 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 14:21:08 | 06/28/2018 14:56:30 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 15:20:02 | 06/28/2018 15:46:18 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 16:44:35 | 06/28/2018 17:09:43 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 17:26:54 | 06/28/2018 17:35:20 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 18:20:17 | 06/28/2018 18:42:42 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 18:50:23 | 06/28/2018 19:07:15 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 19:12:00 | 06/28/2018 20:06:46 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 20:15:26 | 06/28/2018 20:46:14 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 21:12:03 | 06/28/2018 21:12:29 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 21:23:12 | 06/28/2018 21:27:14 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 22:04:46 | 06/28/2018 22:17:00 |
 | 1033 | 06/28/2018 22:58:18 | 06/29/2018 01:21:10 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 02:05:34 | 06/29/2018 02:10:05 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 02:15:52 | 06/29/2018 07:07:20 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 07:46:33 | 06/29/2018 08:06:29 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 08:50:00 | 06/29/2018 08:54:24 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 10:16:49 | 06/29/2018 12:47:49 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 14:11:53 | 06/29/2018 15:02:08 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 15:35:25 | 06/29/2018 16:46:58 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 16:49:12 | 06/29/2018 16:55:00 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 17:23:20 | 06/29/2018 17:50:58 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 19:26:29 | 06/29/2018 19:40:41 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 21:28:30 | 06/29/2018 22:00:50 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 22:40:32 | 06/29/2018 22:41:46 |
 | 1033 | 06/29/2018 23:20:08 | 06/30/2018 01:24:54 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 01:39:53 | 06/30/2018 06:21:02 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 09:17:11 | 06/30/2018 09:17:12 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 09:17:20 | 06/30/2018 09:45:50 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 10:52:58 | 06/30/2018 11:46:47 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 12:28:47 | 06/30/2018 14:05:42 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 15:30:42 | 06/30/2018 15:37:32 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 16:28:27 | 06/30/2018 16:39:04 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 17:13:20 | 06/30/2018 18:09:44 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 19:30:26 | 06/30/2018 20:25:35 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 21:30:45 | 06/30/2018 22:25:15 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 23:27:07 | 06/30/2018 23:27:35 |
 | 1033 | 06/30/2018 23:48:45 | 06/30/2018 23:50:08 |
```

I need to figure out per hour of each unique date, how long a user was logged on (IE StartDate to EndDate).

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974143/7043507) that discusses this and here is my query so far but it does not account for the hours of row 1 spanning 2 dates (6/24 to 6/25)

```
WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) - 1
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N1(N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N2 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N3 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N4 (N)
), SampleData (userid, StartDate, EndDate) AS
(   SELECT  userid, CONVERT(DATETIME2, StartDate), CONVERT(DATETIME2, EndDate)
    FROM (VALUES 
            (1033, '06/24/2018 23:00:52', '06/25/2018 01:24:53'),
            (1033, '06/25/2018 02:01:58', '06/25/2018 02:03:47'),
            (1033, '06/25/2018 03:01:57', '06/25/2018 03:45:59')
        ) d (userid, StartDate, EndDate)
)
SELECT  d.userid,
        [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, d.StartDate),
        [Hour] = CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) + n.Number, 0)),
        Seconds_in = CASE  
                        -- SPECIAL CASE: START HOUR = END HOUR
                        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, d.StartDate) = DATEPART(HOUR, d.EndDate)
                            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d.StartDate, d.EndDate) = 0
                            THEN DATEDIFF(second, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)

                        WHEN CONVERT(DATE, d.StartDate)<CONVERT(DATE, d.EndDate) then ?????

                        -- START HOUR
                        WHEN n.Number = 0
                            THEN 3600 - DATEPART(second, d.StartDate)

                        -- END HOUR
                        WHEN n.Number = DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.StartDate, d.EndDate) 
                            THEN DATEPART(second, d.EndDate)

                        -- FULL HOURS IN BETWEEN START AND END
                        ELSE 3600

                    END
FROM    SampleData d
        INNER JOIN Numbers n 
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.StartDate, d.EndDate)
ORDER BY d.userid,[Date],n.Number;
```

The ideal result would be as follows:

```
 | UserID | Date      | Hour     |  Seconds_in |
 | 1033   | 6/24/2018 | 23:00:00 |  3548       |
 | 1033   | 6/25/2018 | 0:00:00  |  3600       |
 | 1033   | 6/25/2018 | 1:00:00  |  1493       |
 | 1033   | 6/25/2018 | 2:00:00  |  109        |
 | 1033   | 6/25/2018 | 3:00:00  |  2642       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lightly different tack to before

I've created a Temp table - see the [SQLFiddle] for full solution[1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eda42/1)

I've created a Grp and StartDate_Plus column as below

```
;WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) - 1
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N1(N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N2 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N3 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N4 (N)
)
    SELECT
         D.UserId
        ,D.StartDate
        ,D.EndDate
        ,StartDate_Plus = DATEADD(HOUR, N.Number, D.StartDate) --Only for Ordering of ResultSet below
        ,N.Number
        ,Grp = MAX(N.Number)OVER(PARTITION BY UserId, StartDate)
    FROM
        dbo.T1  D
    INNER JOIN Numbers N ON N.Number <= DATEDIFF(HOUR, D.StartDate, D.EndDate)
```

Output like so

```
UserId  StartDate                   EndDate                     StartDate_Plus              Number  Grp
1033    2018-06-24 00:11:51.0000000 2018-06-24 01:03:38.0000000 2018-06-24 00:11:51.0000000 0   1
1033    2018-06-24 00:11:51.0000000 2018-06-24 01:03:38.0000000 2018-06-24 01:11:51.0000000 1   1
1033    2018-06-24 02:12:38.0000000 2018-06-24 02:15:51.0000000 2018-06-24 02:12:38.0000000 0   0
1033    2018-06-24 02:28:08.0000000 2018-06-24 02:36:31.0000000 2018-06-24 02:28:08.0000000 0   0
1033    2018-06-24 03:07:13.0000000 2018-06-24 06:02:05.0000000 2018-06-24 03:07:13.0000000 0   3
1033    2018-06-24 03:07:13.0000000 2018-06-24 06:02:05.0000000 2018-06-24 04:07:13.0000000 1   3
1033    2018-06-24 03:07:13.0000000 2018-06-24 06:02:05.0000000 2018-06-24 05:07:13.0000000 2   3
1033    2018-06-24 03:07:13.0000000 2018-06-24 06:02:05.0000000 2018-06-24 06:07:13.0000000 3   3
```

The StartDate_plus column is just added the [Number] of hours to `StartDate` and `Grp` just to provide a group together multiple rows for the same event

Adding this additional CTE you can then show the Dummy `StartDate_` and `EndDate_` for each hour that an event is more than one hour like so

```
;WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) - 1
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N1(N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N2 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N3 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N4 (N)
),cteStartDate_Plus
AS(
    SELECT
         D.UserId
        ,D.StartDate
        ,D.EndDate
        ,StartDate_Plus = DATEADD(HOUR, N.Number, D.StartDate) --Only for Ordering of ResultSet below
        ,N.Number
        ,Grp = MAX(N.Number)OVER(PARTITION BY UserId, StartDate)
    FROM
        dbo.T1  D
    INNER JOIN Numbers N ON N.Number <= DATEDIFF(HOUR, D.StartDate, D.EndDate)
)
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
         UserId, StartDate, EndDate, Grp
        ,CS.StartDate_Plus
        ,CS.Number
        ,[StartDate_] = CASE --apply some rounding to the StartDate if required
                            WHEN Number = 0 THEN CS.StartDate
                            ELSE DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, CS.StartDate_Plus), 0)
                        END
        ,[EndDate_] =   CASE --apply some rounding to the EndDate if required
                            WHEN CS.Number = CS.Grp THEN CS.EndDate
                            WHEN CS.StartDate_Plus > CS.EndDate THEN CS.EndDate
                            WHEN CS.Number <> CS.Grp AND CS.StartDate_Plus <= CS.EndDate 
                                THEN DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 + DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, CS.StartDate_Plus)),CS.StartDate_Plus)), 0) 
                        END
        ,[Hour] = CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CS.StartDate_Plus), 0))
    FROM
        cteStartDate_Plus CS
    ORDER BY
        UserId, CS.StartDate_Plus
```

Then encapsulating the above query into another CTE called CteDummyDates the following query just provide you will the results you want

```
SELECT
      UserId
     ,[Date] = CONVERT(DATE, DD.StartDate_Plus)
     ,DD.[Hour]
    ,[Seconds_in] = DATEDIFF(SECOND, DD.StartDate_, DD.EndDate_)
FROM
    cteDummyDates DD
ORDER BY
    DD.UserId, DD.StartDate_
```

Output

```
UserId  Date        Hour        Seconds_in
1033    2018-06-24  00:00:00    2889
1033    2018-06-24  01:00:00    218
1033    2018-06-24  02:00:00    193
1033    2018-06-24  02:00:00    503
1033    2018-06-24  03:00:00    3167
1033    2018-06-24  04:00:00    3600
1033    2018-06-24  05:00:00    3600
1033    2018-06-24  06:00:00    125
1033    2018-06-24  07:00:00    1
1033    2018-06-24  08:00:00    2441
1033    2018-06-24  09:00:00    3600
```

Comment: Thanks! This is looking promising after all!

Unfortunately I am getting seconds_in over 3600 when I apply this to my whole dataset. I have added in more data to illustrate this. When I add in those values to your query, it produces seconds>3600.

Comment: Thanks again! This is coming along great! You are awesome!

I am now seeing some data in my dataset where the StartDates may be back to back for some reason (IE user logs on twice in a row then logs off) This is giving me two logon times for one logoff time and using your query, giving me times>3600. I am racking my brain trying to figure out how to exclude these outliers. Essentially I need to exclude data where there are 2 or more logon times before a logoff. 

In your SQL Fiddle, if you add the value (1033, '2018-06-24 00:11:50', '2018-06-24 01:03:38') as the first value you will see.

Comment: Changing the nature of questions or adding additional variations is frowned upon on SO especially when you've got answers to the original problem. If this response answers your question then accept it as an answer. Open a new question, link back to this, with the additional variant.